# DirectMethod is not getting called, Ext js 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am very new to EXTJS. I am using 3.4 version which is old one.
Have defined the controller and Use DirectMethod for combo box value fill up.

But controller's direct method in not being called.

## My Code below

```
public class Controller { //Controller to fetch the data
    @DirectMethod
    public String fetchData() {
        System.out.println("Controller");
        ArrayList < ComboDataVo > da = null;
        Dao dao = new Dao();
        try {
            da = dao.retrieveUserData();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("In Controller.................");
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        System.out.println("Data: " + gson.toJson(da));
        return gson.toJson(da);
    }
}
```

## Main js

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    //Menu

    new Ext.Toolbar({
        renderTo: document.body,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tbbutton',
            text: 'Button',
            helpfile: 'director',
            handler: Movies.showHelp
        }, {
            xtype: 'tbfill'
        }, {
            xtype: 'tbseparator'
        }, {
            xtype: 'tbbutton',
            text: 'Menu Button',
            menu: [{
                text: 'Panel1'

            }, {
                text: 'Panel2'
            }]
        }]
    })

    //Form

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var movie_form = new Ext.FormPanel({
        renderTo: document.body,
        frame: true,
        width: 800,

        collapsible: true,
        title: 'Movie Information',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            name: 'mtype',
            fieldLabel: 'Horror Movie'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Local Data',
            xtype: 'combo',
            name: 'genre',
            mode: 'local',
            store: dstore, // Calling this one for the Combo data
            displayField: 'user_id'
        }, {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            fieldLabel: 'Decription',
            anchor: '100%',
            maxLength: 5
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'extra Comments',
            xtype: 'htmleditor',
            anchor: '100%'
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Panel',
            layout: 'border',
            collapsible: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'PanelTextBox1',
                name: 'panelTxt1',
                region: 'west'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'PanelTextBox2',
                name: 'panelTxt2',
                region: 'south'
            }]

        }]
    });
});


//Data Store js

var dstore = new Ext.data.Store({
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields: ['user_id', 'emp_no']
    }),

    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        directFn: 'Controller.fetchData'
    },

    autoLoad: true
});
```

Can someone please help me on this?
Appreciate your help!

Thanks,
Dhaval

Comment: why not AJAX call ?

Comment: @Frank, I have to Load while page gets load or Component gets load? So i might not need ajax call for the same?

Comment: Is there any scope for Controller that i have to define?